# How do I clone a git repo on a remote windows filesystem?

Tags: windows, git, github, filesystems

Is it possible to clone a git repo on remote windows filsystem without map a network drive?

I'm in:

```
C:\Users\<username>
```

I'm trying to:

```
git clone <https_repo_link> \\server\path\to\clone\dir
```

And I get the following result:

> fatal: could not create leading directories of
> \server\path\to\clone\dir

Comment: Have you tried ssh into the server?

Comment: I haven't tried yet, I was looking for a simpler way